# Python statistics.median_grouped returns value outside of input range

Tags: python, statistics, median

I'm analyzing some data and got this list, median_grouped of which seems to be outside of range of values in the list.

[screen:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5whvO.png)

```
statistics.median_grouped(rcdistance)
-0.1250640605965987
min(rcdistance)
0.0
```

Here's the list:

```html
[0.0, 0.21098454268727887, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 6.800735254367722, 6.800735254367722, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.3691164850450193, 0.8341463454328069, 6.954672651889972, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.894523526205462, 0.5202041513165154, 0.3195953715186193, 1.19650727442225, 1.9829608504017993, 0.320822054594543, 0.8021892543724501, 0.06639592707563217, 0.33791893636471976, 1.3469748280785028, 0.46225975601521924, 0.29146628081088805, 0.31432316149828754, 0.24174865833529519, 0.10137129170776715, 2.07576600608641, 0.2615844609784234, 0.6481662780506829, 0.13578192040175857, 0.13470214233110803, 0.34278013217398423, 0.09326076007769707, 0.4336006232739294, 0.6007209936117036, 2.8535831869013726, 0.7286885646881327, 0.6175406688934962, 0.6432741795490186, 0.25089604017432937, 0.2247559442381167, 0.10569371849097034, 0.13555324220681084, 11.575372015987313, 0.13669258957306155, 1.634337739537961, 0.7023579970496473, 0.9488940841470294, 1.9556804571337925, 0.8370864316757329, 1.2024907508700595, 2.2424077713328843, 0.49703062007687854, 0.7817924904836159, 2.3319974222716975, 1.8335319342837306, 0.0, 3.28868490484547, 1.4314796804850678, 1.3638514553202294, 0.3513379545492983, 0.16043624593306288, 12.960363339703447, 1.4495399509870706, 0.2861815531492466, 0.23131921608674785, 0.07470703125, 0.3156641038900055, 0.12637431907281702, 0.6356548946706172, 2.1073361751465227, 0.1782201479382565, 1.3450383951599099, 0.8871288611532409, 1.4173304274383594, 0.14168172737548348, 0.3703729958352881, 1.658888478625415, 1.2477698697766813, 1.7575586601929727, 2.167596692301178, 2.051780602511496, 0.37814640268331945, 2.1041473318539876, 1.1896854668558041, 0.9250246006039865, 1.3271447098141402, 1.6116094170310153, 1.0963143124740196, 1.4711895830945183, 0.1623601238081846, 1.577846710293568, 0.07569225630868787, 1.200957612567313, 0.18243840079429852, 0.7718713876122335, 0.6783927775524854, 1.7536286642036438, 1.7548529400031645, 0.16162109375, 0.6676365879769467, 0.2727575294371441, 13.361847527117655, 2.2281143134718224, 0.5390126302014291, 0.9547223635736837, 0.17379417516519388, 0.15405041289356222, 0.918123792176202, 0.2754296890581234, 0.5438064589731, 1.6679939428923882, 0.33831407770944383, 0.13401630343709894, 0.4036704845489422, 2.4687540199150484, 1.364673723134251, 1.462182233800534, 0.2524997193740947, 0.6879091779122948, 0.07512909587034285, 1.168234753379213, 0.460947068971782, 0.9278222935828773, 0.5815480934256779, 0.15330106772382537, 0.16744291813233583, 0.11594392249731117, 2.424850113159381, 0.8373170681343546, 4.714464894570124, 0.8284206942102329, 6.691576922679101, 0.9362133734023534, 0.3749359394034013, 0.7812593459523988, 5.344434281645955, 0.34577846245001914, 2.6886532105742007, 0.261063966541952, 0.14849250175991532, 0.3498228476287005]
```

Comment: Read [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.median_grouped) carefully. One grouping for your data is between `-0.5` and `+0.5` given the default interval of 1 and since so many of your data points are in this group, you can easily get a `median_grouped` value near the lower end.

Comment: I've red it but too stupid to figure it out, thank you.

Comment: `... the data are rounded, so that each value represents the midpoint of data classes, e.g. 1 is the midpoint of the class 0.5–1.5, 2 is the midpoint of 1.5–2.5, 3 is the midpoint of 2.5–3.5, etc. With the data given, the middle value falls somewhere in the class 3.5–4.5, and interpolation is used to estimate it.` I'm sorry, I can't explain it more clearly.